# Accessing special Data in the PrinterDriver via C (like duplex printing)

Tags: c

moin-moin,

I know, I am the only living person, still writing software for OS/2, but maybe someone can give me a hint:

For a customer I need to print a lot of different Reports on many pre-printed papers, some one-side, some double-sided, orientation landscaped or portrait (so, there are many different combinations)

the option i use now is to assign every possible report to its own printer-driver and let the user set the apropriate settings once for those drivers.

what i need is a more generic way. I want the user just to provide the driver, and I myself want to set Orientation and Sideness (and even the paper feed) programatically.

Any suggestions if this is possible? And how?

Thanks,
Peter

Comment: OS/2!? wow I don't think you'll find anyone even here that still actively programs on that OS..

Comment: Since you've got direct access to the serial or parallel port, why not write the relevant control codes directly to the port? Is it the same printer in every case?

Comment: oh, i did not mention, that them are network-printers, and there are different brands (f.e. Kyocera, Lexmark).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

okay, just to close this and give a solution for anyone beaten with the same problem.

i installed pmpdfwriter, installed a postscript printer driver associated with this output device and replaced the gsos2.exe (which is called by the printersystem) with a small selfwritten program, that analyses the filename. If there are my special "parameters" in the name, i copy the generated PostScript file (from the printer driver) to a network device, alongside with a small shell script "lpr -P printer -other options for duplex and orientation and paper feed" which i get from a database and a small selfwritten "printer configuration application", else i call the original gsos2.exe. On the network side there is a unix server, that looks for the scripts and calls those scripts ("on UNIX all is text, on OS/2 most is binary"). With this technique, i have the option to print stacks of different reports on different papers (if they are fed in the same printer) together without mixing them with other print requests.

Answer (score 0):

Though it's been 17 years since I was an OS/2 developer, I recall that around 1.3 - 2.0 the printing API operated in a similar manner to Win3.1/WinNT 3.51.

Your question has kindled a quest for me to hunt through SO for unanswered OS/2 questions, brb !